# easy_install launches as a terminal and closes on its own, how to avoid that

Tags: python, easy-install, activepython

Trying to install various packages on a Windows 7 64 bit and learned that [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) helps (as it includes easy_install among others).

It surely seems pretty robust. However I'm trying to easy_install a few packages and its failing.

The problem is that the easy_install.exe actually launches in a new terminal and closes on its own, even when there is a problem, how do I avoid that ?

Anyone faced this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `easy_install` is trying to relaunch itself as Administrator in a different window which quits immediately after easy_install exits. Try running easy_install from an [Administrator prompt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc947813%28WS.10%29.aspx).

As a [recommendation](http://code.activestate.com/help/faq/#how-is-pypm-related-to-pip-and-easy_install) for ActivePython users, easy_install should only be used a last resort; you should first try installing packages using PyPM (included in ActivePython). See http://code.activestate.com/pypm/

Comment: Thanks the Administrator prompt option worked !! Tried using pypm but it isn't working in the virtualenv I've created even after using the --virtualenv=PATH option.

Comment: @PlanetUnknown - Could you please let me know why PyPM is not working with virtualenv for you? As I'm the primary developer of PyPM, I can look into fixing it.

Comment: Today it is showing I need an enterprise edition, but I'm pretty sure it was showing something diff. that day. I'l let you know if I hit upon one again.

Comment: @PlanetUnknown - Get the 32-bit ActivePython as that doesn't require paid edition, and you can download packages for free using PyPM.

Answer (score 0):

try specifying the command like so: 
c:\python27\python.exe -m easy_install Django==1.6.5v