# How can I make easy_install.exe not open in a separate window?

Tags: python, windows-7-x64, easy-install, cpython

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [activepython : easy_install launches as a terminal and closes on its own, how to avoid that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212823/activepython-easy-install-launches-as-a-terminal-and-closes-on-its-own-how-to)

I just installed setuptools for Windows, and I'm trying to use it:

```
easy_install.exe --help
```

This fires up a new command window, runs Python and the easy_install script, and quickly shuts down before I have a chance to look at the output!

As a workaround, I found easy_install-script.py, which I can run manually. But my question is how can I make easy_install not spawn a separate command window? (It's pretty useless as it is now)

**Edit** - I've tried the solution that is pointed to in the [dup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212823/activepython-easy-install-launches-as-a-terminal-and-closes-on-its-own-how-to), and it does't work. I'm not using ActivePython, but rather cpython, under Windows 64 bit. Could this be enough of a difference to keep this question open?

Comment: do you run `easy_install.exe --help` from a shell (`cmd.exe`)? it doesn't spawn a new command window then, here.

Comment: It sounds like you're running the above from a shortcut, is that right? My ancient recollection, from a decade ago when I actually used windows, is that you can set a flag in the shortcut that keeps the window open. I don't know if that still applies though.

Comment: @ex, @senderle - yeah, I'm running it from cmd, not as a shortcut.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212823/activepython-easy-install-launches-as-a-terminal-and-closes-on-its-own-how-to

Comment: @ax, @Jeff - the solution there didn't work for me. Perhaps the conditions are a bit different. I'm using cpython, not ActivePython. Could this be related to the fact I'm on Windows 7 64 bit? (I have python 64 bit installed)