# How do I force easy_install.exe to print output in the current command window?

Tags: python, windows-7, pip, easy-install

I am running Windows 7 64 bit and have installed easy_install.  When I run easy_install from the command prompt it opens another window for the output and quickly closes before I am able to examine what has been done.

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362948/how-can-i-make-easy-install-exe-not-open-in-a-separate-window) but think it may have been closed prematurely as the solution that the closed ticket referred to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212823/activepython-easy-install-launches-as-a-terminal-and-closes-on-its-own-how-to) does not work on my system.

When I run the cmd window as Administrator and then execute (for example):

```
$ easy_install pip
```

I get the same behavior ... another cmd window flashes and then I am returned to the prompt with no output. How then do I force easy_install to output its results in the current window?

UPDATE: (additional information) This same behavior is exhibited when using pip.exe and virtualenv.exe as well.  This must have something to do with how these executables are built and how they interact with windows 7 64bit.

Comment: It would help if you posted the command line you are using.  Assuming it starts with "easy_install", does prefixing that with "python" help?

Comment: @ʇsәɹoɈ It does appear that there is an `easy_install-script.py` installed in the `Scripts` folder.  When I run `python easy_install-script.py pip` the output stays in the window.  So I guess this is an acceptable work around for now ... but the question remains on what is going on with the separate window and that it appears that some systems do not resolve the issue by running as Administrator.

Comment: I tried reproducing this just for the heck of it, but couldn't.  Since I don't have windows 7, I think I'll let someone else handle this.  It might help if you post the version of python are you using, the contents of your PATH environment variable, the exact command line you're running and the directory you're in when you run it.

Comment: Funny enough. Today I installed Python 2.6 on my brother's laptop (running Win7 32 bit). When I installed distribute and I saw the exact same problem. I uninstalled distribute and installed setuptools, still not working properly. But strangely, pip works well for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python packages open new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814759/python-packages-open-new-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the issue was the version of `setuptools` that I was using.  I had installed `python-2.7.1.amd64` and then installed `setuptools-0.6c12dev.win-amd64-py2.7`.

In the the quest to grab a 64 bit setuptool - I failed to notice the "dev" part of the filename.

It turns out when I uninstalled it and then installed `setuptools-0.6c11.win32-py2.7` all output stays in the console.  There seems to be some issues with the newer "c12" version.

On a related note - this fixes the same problem with the use of `pip` and `virtualenv` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 has made user privileges a huge hassle. It's intended to protect the average user but gives developers headaches.

Run cmd.exe as Admin (right-click on the .exe and then select "Run as Administrator") and this problem should be solved.

I've also seen this happen if you install a virtualenv and then change the parent directory name. The path seems to be hardcoded in various files when you install the virtualenv, so changing anything upstream gives it fits. You can either grep/wingrep all the files that contain the path and manually update it, or do a Google search and find the "correct" way to fix the problem (I think there is one).

Answer (score 0):

First try this:

- Backup your `Scripts\easy_install.exe` to somewhere else
- Go to `Lib\site-packages\site-packages\distribute-0.6.13-py2.6.egg\setuptools` and copy `cli.exe` to `Scripts\`, then rename it to `easy_install.exe`
- Run and see the result.

I'm using [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) here, if you are using [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) and the above steps doesn't work, I suggest you give distribute a try.

Comment: Thanks for input - but unfortunately it results in the same behavior as described in the original question.  Another window opens and disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (new window behavior displayed across a number of libraries) - I believe it was the result of the compilation method used for the setuptools binary.

I had originally used the compiled binaries that were available here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

I just had to uninstall the setuptools binary and install one available here:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Presumably you'd also be able to compile your own version should you need a win64 binary.

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem with `pip` and `easy_install` on Windows 7. You can just use Powershell (could be found in accessories). It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**i too faced the same problem once, here is an easy and quick solution**

try specifying the commands like so:

c:\python27\python.exe -m easy_install Django==1.6.5v

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me, though when installing scipy this way I receive an error saying `error: no lapack/blas resources found`