# python packages open new window

Tags: windows, command-line

I installed python27 64-bit on windows 7. I also have setuptools and pip installed. Now when I execute command in windows console new console window appear, message is printed in it and close before i can read something from it. e. g. I installed yolk and when type yolk -l in cmd it shows me all packages in new cmd window and close immediately. What should I do if I want all messages in main command window?

Comment: Thank you, it works 100%! Others have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494080/how-do-i-force-easy-install-exe-to-print-output-in-the-current-command-window

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you run `pip` or `easy_install` from the command-line, your system will be starting `easy_install.exe` or `pip.exe`. As of Python 2.7 x64 these executables have a manifest file to satisfy Windows 7's UAC requirements. You can read a little more about this [here](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute/issue/143/easy_install-opens-new-console-cant-read-the), but in short, because the applications could be running with different permissions, a new window is opened.

I don't believe there's a proper fix to get around this, short of downgrading. However, you can *bypass* the problem by not using the executable files.

Back up and then remove `pip.exe`, `easy_install.exe`, and `fab.exe` (if you have Fabric).

Create a bunch of batch files matching the original binaries' names, and put them in the same folder that had the binaries (default `C:\Python27\Scripts`).

**easy_install.bat**

```
@echo off
easy_install-script.py %*
```

**pip.bat**

```
@echo off
pip-script.py %*
```

**fab.bat**

```
@echo off
fab-script.py %*
```

With these in place, you should find your command-line use of these tools doesn't spawn a new window. Happy hacking.

Comment: Thanks for the great tip! However, if you're like me and you like to associate your .py files with your IDE then this might not behave the way you want. To make sure easy_install runs in the python shell as expected, change the second line to python %~dp0\easy_install-script.py %*

Answer (score 1):

I tried these, but still a new terminal opened. So i ran the cmd as an administrator, and python worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but it repairs when I **turn off** an **Antivirus**.

Answer (score 1):

try specifying the commands like so: 
c:\python27\python.exe -m easy_install Django==1.6.5v

Answer (score 0):

try specifying the commands like so: 
c:\python27\python.exe -m pip install Django==1.6.5v