# Python code not executing in Powershell

Tags: python-2.7, powershell

I recently installed Python 2.7 on my windows 7 system and have been following the book named learnpythonthehardway.

Now, I have properly included Python 2.7 as one of my environment variables. However, when I execute `>python ex5.py` in the Powershell terminal, no error is shown, but a new window opens up and closes in just the other instant, and I get a new command line on Powershell.

Whereas, when done by the author, he gets the output in Powershell itself in the next line. I tried idle too but some scripts written in the book only run with Powershell.

What could the issue be?

Comment: Could be this http://stackoverflow.com/q/5814759/1751302

Comment: Which python distribution do you have installed?

Comment: @noam Thanks a lot! this was the same problem i was facing.

Comment: Problem solved!! I just had to run Powershell as an administrator.

Comment: @Hart I have the python 2.7.10 downloaded from the python.org site itself.